# PyQT4/Python33 issues

Tags: qt4, pyqt4, python-3.3

I have installed PyQt 4 for use with Python33 on my windows 7 machine, I followed the instructions on riverbank and everything seems to have be done correctly, however, I tried a simple example to create a basic found online, which compiled but doesnt display any GUI. any ideas?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Hello')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks

Comment: Please avoid using tabs for indentation, use 4 spaces. Most editors have settings to be able to use the tab key on the keyboard to input 4 spaces instead of a tab. At least do this when you want to post the code on SO otherwise the indentation will be shown all messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply defined a function. You must also call it to see the widget:

I have installed PyQt 4 for use with Python33 on my windows 7 machine, I followed the instructions on riverbank and everything seems to have be done correctly, however, I tried a simple example to create a basic found online, which compiled but doesnt display any GUI. any ideas?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Hello')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':  #avoids execution when imported.
    main()
```

Launching the program with `$python the-program.py` should show the window.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have fixed it. Thanks